# Httpost of EditReport is not commiting changes back to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to mvc and entityframework coding and have run into a problem that I cant seem to figure out. Any help would be very much appreciated.

I have the following model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Services.Providers;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HAZID.Core.Models
{
    public class HAZID_Forms : HAZID_Base_Entity
    {

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Workers_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "HAZID_Workers_Id_Error_Msg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int HAZID_Workers_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Supervisors_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "HAZID_Supervisor_Id_Error_Msg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int HAZID_Supervisors_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Form_DateTime", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public DateTime HAZID_Form_DateTime { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_District_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "HAZID_District_Id_Error_Msg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int HAZID_District_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Hazard_Location", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "HAZID_Hazard_Location_Error_Msg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string HAZID_Hazard_Location { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Hazard_Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "HAZID_Hazard_Description_Error_Msg", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string HAZID_Hazard_Description { get; set; }
        public string HAZID_Hazard_Description_Short { get { return HAZID_Hazard_Description.ToString().SubStringTo(30); } }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Workers_Suggstion", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string HAZID_Workers_Suggstion { get; set; }
        public string HAZID_Workers_Suggstion_Short { get { return HAZID_Workers_Suggstion.ToString().SubStringTo(30); } }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Position", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string HAZID_Position { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Status_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int? HAZID_Status_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int? HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Control_Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string HAZID_Control_Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Person_Responsible_Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public string HAZID_Person_Responsible_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Applcability_To_Others_Flag", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public bool HAZID_Applcability_To_Others_Flag { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int? HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Risk_Probability_Id", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        public int? HAZID_Risk_Probability_Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "HAZID_Action_Taken", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string HAZID_Action_Taken { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and two viewmodels

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HAZID.Core.Models;

namespace HAZID.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HAZID_Form_View_Model
    {
        public HAZID_Forms HAZID_Form { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Branch_Districts> HAZID_Branch_Districts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Persons> HAZID_Persons { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Hazard_Types> HAZID_Hazard_Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types> HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types> HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Statuses> HAZID_Statuses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HAZID.Core.Models;

namespace HAZID.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class HAZID_Forms_View_Model
    {
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Forms> HAZID_Forms { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Branch_Districts> HAZID_Branch_Districts { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Hazard_Types> HAZID_Hazard_Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types> HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types> HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Statuses> HAZID_Statuses { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HAZID_Persons> HAZID_Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller looks like this

```
using HAZID.Core.Contracts;
using HAZID.Core.Models;
using HAZID.Core.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HAZID.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class HAZID_ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Forms> hazidForms;
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Branch_Districts> hazidBranchDistricts;
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Hazard_Types> hazidHazardTypes;
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types> hazidRiskSeverityTypes;
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types> hazidRiskProbabilityTypes;
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Statuses> hazidStatuses;
        IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Persons> hazidPersons;

        public HAZID_ApplicationController(IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Forms> hazidFormContext, IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Branch_Districts> hazidBranchDistrictContext, 
                                           IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Hazard_Types> hazidHazardTypeContext, IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types> hazidRiskSeverityTypeContext,
                                           IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types> hazidRiskProbabilityTypeContext, IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Statuses> hazidStatusContext, 
                                           IHAZID_Repository<HAZID_Persons> hazidPersonContext)
        {
            this.hazidForms = hazidFormContext;
            this.hazidBranchDistricts = hazidBranchDistrictContext;
            this.hazidHazardTypes = hazidHazardTypeContext;
            this.hazidRiskSeverityTypes = hazidRiskSeverityTypeContext;
            this.hazidRiskProbabilityTypes = hazidRiskProbabilityTypeContext;
            this.hazidStatuses = hazidStatusContext;
            this.hazidPersons = hazidPersonContext;
        }

        // GET: HASSApplication
        public ActionResult ListReports()
        {
            HAZID_Forms_View_Model hazidFormsViewModel = new HAZID_Forms_View_Model();

            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Forms = hazidForms.Collection().ToList();
            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Branch_Districts = hazidBranchDistricts.Collection();
            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Hazard_Types = hazidHazardTypes.Collection();
            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types = hazidRiskSeverityTypes.Collection();
            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types = hazidRiskProbabilityTypes.Collection();
            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Statuses = hazidStatuses.Collection();
            hazidFormsViewModel.HAZID_Persons = hazidPersons.Collection();
            return View(hazidFormsViewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult EditReport(int id)
        {
            HAZID_Forms hazidFormToEdit = hazidForms.Find(id);
            if (hazidFormToEdit == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                HAZID_Form_View_Model hazidFormViewModel = new HAZID_Form_View_Model();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Form = hazidFormToEdit;
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Branch_Districts = hazidBranchDistricts.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Hazard_Types = hazidHazardTypes.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types = hazidRiskSeverityTypes.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types = hazidRiskProbabilityTypes.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Statuses = hazidStatuses.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Persons = hazidPersons.Collection();
                return View(hazidFormViewModel);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditReport(HAZID_Form_View_Model hazidFormViewModel, int id)
        {
            HAZID_Forms hazidFormToEdit = hazidForms.Find(id);

            if (hazidFormToEdit == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(hazidFormViewModel);
                }

                hazidFormToEdit = hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Form;
                hazidForms.Commit();

                return RedirectToAction("ListReports");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult ViewForm(int id)
        {
            HAZID_Forms hazidFormToView = hazidForms.Find(id);
            if (hazidFormToView == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                HAZID_Form_View_Model hazidFormViewModel = new HAZID_Form_View_Model();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Form = hazidFormToView;
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Branch_Districts = hazidBranchDistricts.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Hazard_Types = hazidHazardTypes.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types = hazidRiskSeverityTypes.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types = hazidRiskProbabilityTypes.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Statuses = hazidStatuses.Collection();
                hazidFormViewModel.HAZID_Persons = hazidPersons.Collection();
                return View(hazidFormViewModel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Edit View looks like this

```
@model HAZID.Core.ViewModels.HAZID_Form_View_Model

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Report";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>HASS Report Details</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Workers_Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Form_DateTime)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_District_Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Supervisors_Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Location)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Description)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Workers_Suggstion)

    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Workers_Id)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Persons.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Workers_Id).Full_Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Position)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Position)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Form_DateTime)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Form_DateTime.ToString())
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Supervisors_Id)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Persons.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Supervisors_Id).Full_Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            @{
                var hazidDistrictName = string.Empty;
                if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en")
                {
                    hazidDistrictName = Model.HAZID_Branch_Districts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_District_Id).English_Description.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    hazidDistrictName = Model.HAZID_Branch_Districts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_District_Id).French_Description.ToString();
                }
            }
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_District_Id)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(hazidDistrictName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Location)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Location)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Description)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Description)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                @Html.CustomLabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Workers_Suggstion)
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                @Html.Raw(Model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Workers_Suggstion)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Status_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Status_Id, new SelectList(Model.HAZID_Statuses, "Id", Resources.Resource.HAZID_Column_Select), Resources.Resource.HAZID_Status_Id_Select, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "HAZID_Form_HAZID_Status_Id" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Action_Taken, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Action_Taken, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100% !important; min-width:600px; height:100px" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id, new SelectList(Model.HAZID_Hazard_Types, "Id", Resources.Resource.HAZID_Column_Select), Resources.Resource.HAZID_Hazard_Type_Select, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "HAZID_Form_HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id, new SelectList(Model.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Types, "Id", Resources.Resource.HAZID_Column_Select), Resources.Resource.HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id_Select, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "HAZID_Form_HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Risk_Probability_Id, new SelectList(Model.HAZID_Risk_Probability_Types, "Id", Resources.Resource.HAZID_Column_Select), Resources.Resource.HAZID_Risk_Probability_Id_Select, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "HAZID_Form_HAZID_Risk_Probability_Id" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Control_Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Control_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100% !important; min-width:600px; height:100px" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Control_Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Person_Responsible_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Person_Responsible_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Person_Responsible_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Applcability_To_Others_Flag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.HAZID_Form.HAZID_Applcability_To_Others_Flag)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "ListReports")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#HAZID_Form_HAZID_Status_Id").select2();
            $("#HAZID_Form_HAZID_Hazard_Type_Id").select2();
            $("#HAZID_Form_HAZID_Risk_Severity_Id").select2();
            $("#HAZID_Form_HAZID_Risk_Probability_Id").select2();
            $('.select2-container').css("width", "100%");
        });
    </script>
}
```

My problem is when I click the <kbd>Save</kbd> the data is there but after the commit and redirect the data was not saved to the database.

If someone can help me it would be very much appreciated.

Edited: As Requested here is my DataAccess Code

```
using HAZID.Core.Contracts;
using HAZID.Core.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HAZID.DataAccess.Sql
{
    public class HAZID_Sql_Repository<T> : IHAZID_Repository<T> where T : HAZID_Base_Entity
    {
        internal HAZID_DataContext hazidContext;
        internal DbSet<T> hazidDbSet;

        public HAZID_Sql_Repository(HAZID_DataContext hazidDataContext)
        {
            this.hazidContext = hazidDataContext;
            this.hazidDbSet = hazidDataContext.Set<T>();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Collection()
        {
            return hazidDbSet;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            hazidContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(int Id)
        {
            var t = Find(Id);
            if (hazidContext.Entry(t).State == EntityState.Detached)
                hazidDbSet.Attach(t);

            hazidDbSet.Remove(t);
        }

        public T Find(int Id)
        {
            return hazidDbSet.Find(Id);
        }

        public void Insert(T t)
        {

            hazidDbSet.Add(t);
        }

        public void Update(T t)
        {
            hazidDbSet.Attach(t);
            hazidContext.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shae code of the `commit` method.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that step. Modified the Request and added in the commit code

Comment: Try calling method `hazidForms.Update(hazidFormToEdit)` before `Commit` method.